# Ioctl params values (cmd and arg) are showing same, even i sent different values

Tags: c

I'm trying to read the ioctl params sent from the application. but in driver side the cmd and arg (3rd and 4th arguments) values are coming same, even if i send different values. both params showing the argument value which isent from application. Can any one help me to solve this?
here my code :
application :  ioctl(fd,0,1).
driver ioctl : cmd = 1.
               arg = 1.

```
int char_ioctl(struct inode *inode_num, struct file *fp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg) 
{ 
   int ret = 0,i; 

   printk("cmd : %d\n",cmd); 
   printk("arg : %d\n",(unsigned long)arg); 

   switch(cmd) 
   { 
      case GETCAPACITY: 
         ret = BUFFER_MAX_SIZE; 
         break; 

      default : 
         break; 
    } 

   return ret; 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the driver ioctl fucntion?

Comment: Can you show more code to us? Try to make a minimal self-contained example.

Comment: int char_ioctl(struct inode *inode_num, struct file *fp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
        int ret = 0,i;
        printk("cmd : %d\n",cmd);
        printk("arg : %d\n",(unsigned long)arg);
        switch(cmd)
        {
                case GETCAPACITY:
                        ret = BUFFER_MAX_SIZE;
                        break;

                default :
                break;
        }


        return ret;
}

Comment: Please find the driver ioctl code added above

Comment: driver Ioctl  function is getting called and printing cmd and arg values same.

Comment: Edit the code into your question and format it properly ... it's almost impossible to read in a comment.  Also show your _multiple_ calls from the application side. Remember: it's common to pass addresses in as the function-specific parameters, so you _may_ be getting the same address pointing to different values (depending on how you are calling things).

Comment: Standard ioctl has 3 parameter. Which function is callin the one you posted?